# About the calendar on the top bar

Tags: unity, calendar

So Ubuntu has this calendar on the top bar(Unity). Now whenever I open it and click on a day, it gets highlighted with bright orange color. If I close it now and open it again after like 1 or 2 days, the highlighted color still stays on the day I selected before, creating confusion because it is obviously not that day anymore.

Is there anyway I can fix this?

Comment: That's a bug. File a bug report.

Comment: It seems that this behavior is not present on Ubuntu 14.04
I vaguely remember this being an issue in older version of Ubuntu, but the problem has been fixed. Which Ubuntu version are you using?

Comment: It was indeed a bug, now fixed in 14.04. https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-datetime/+bug/793450

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/indicator-datetime/+bug/793450 - thanks to aibara-iduas for the link.